# Past simple without would for an action done many times

Tags: past-tense

I saw in the Pogues' song "a pair of brown eyes" this sentence:

> I left the place sometimes crawling sometimes walking,

it seems that the guy from the song left many times the place where he was so why not would leave as it is not a single event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the answer given is fine for an habitual action, that is *not* what's actually being described in the song.

Here is the line you gave (from the website [SongMeanings](http://songmeanings.com/songs/view/51723/)), along with its immediately prior line:

> So drunk to hell I left the place
>   Sometimes crawling sometimes walking

In this single event, the person is simply too drunk to walk for a long period of time. Therefore, they sometimes crawl and sometimes walk.

Answer (score 3):

You can indicate a habitual action by using **would** or **used to**:

> He **used to** leave the office at exactly 5pm. 
>   He **would** leave the office at exactly 5pm.

But you can also indicate that a past simple event happened repeatedly:

> He left the office at exactly 5pm **every day**.

The use of sometimes... sometimes gives the same indication that we are talking about something that happens repeatedly.